# GTK: limiting font choices on font selection dialogs?

Tags: linux, fonts, gtk

As the end user, when I am presented with a font selection dialog (e.g. gvim > <kbd>edit</kbd> > <kbd>select font...</kbd>) it contains tons of variations that are but noise.

I do not care to see individual entries for "font X", "font X italic", "font X bold", "font X italic bold".

How Do i hide those variations and leave only the "regular" font faces showing on that list?